# Maintaining Gunicorn on Linux

Tags: shell-script, python3

I have a flask application, and running that with gunicorn with 5 threads. And when I check ps for gunicorn I see 5 process running which is expected. But I don't easy way to kill them.

Comment: Do all of the processes have the same name?

Comment: Yeah, it will be 5 threads though.

Answer (score 0):

As they all have the same name, you can kill all of the processes with `pkill` regardless of the number of threads:

```
pkill <process-name>
```

Comment: Thank u for that. I am looking for a graceful shutdown method, instead of killing it.

Comment: @Vajra You might be better off with a script that can exit the application. If that's what you want, try StackOverflow as it's more for programming.

Comment: Understand, will post there. Thank you @Nasir